# Nextcloud: Can’t create or write into the data directory /var/nc_data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, php, nginx

I'm getting the above error. What I tried so far:

- checked the permissions. I even did `chmod 777 /var/nc_data -R`
- first included all used party in open_basedir in my php.ini. When that didn't work, I commented it out completely (in fpm and cli php.ini)
- checked if SELinux is active. It isn't.

I don't have any more ideas to start with. I run an ubuntu server 18.04 inside a Hyper-V virtual machine. I use nginx 1.14.0, mariadb 10.1.29, php 7.2 and nextcloud 13.0.2.

Does someone have an idea?

Or could tell me where more error details could be logged so I have something to start with. nginx and php logs just have notices in them.

Thank you guys in advance :)

Marin

PS: Nextcloud vHost configuration: https://pastebin.com/wZJLp0rx

PPS: Nextcloud config.php:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'oc2xpzs4xkog',
);
```

(it's not much written in because it's not set up yet)

Comment: `ls -l /var/nc_data` this folder should belong to apache user

Comment: When I am in /var and type ls -la I get the following output:

drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4096 Mai 16 08:24 nc_data

Comment: So the folder does belong to the www-data user. I did forget in my question to say that I did chown www-data:www-data /var/nc_data -R

Comment: I think the correct usage is `chown -R www-data:www-data /yourfolder` Though in this case it is probably impactless. put your nginx vhost configuration and [edit] your question do not answer in comment. Comment could be deleted any time.

Comment: also add your nextcloud config.php file

Comment: it may be that I confused the chown command when I wrote it, I don't work that often with linux servers, but the command did work and the ls showed correct ownership, so that should be fine.
I edited the question and added the two config files. config.php is not of much use I guess...

Comment: Two matching reports. [Report1](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/can-t-create-or-write-into-the-data-directory/10249) solved by in PHP Settings defining `open_basedir` as ‘none’.  [Report2](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/cant-create-or-write-into-the-data-directory/10184) solved by "set the directory to `/home/wwwroot/data`".

Comment: Setting open_basedir to 'none' doesn't solve the problem. Setting the directory to another path such as the default path /var/www/nextcloud/data solves the problem, but I mounted another drive at /var/nc_data that I want to use.

Comment: I will try to reinstall the virtual machine and mount the other drive at /var/www/nextcloud/data

Comment: It may be that `/var/www/` has some special permissions or be required by the software by some obscure configuration item.

Comment: Is the */var/nc_data* mount point using a read-only filesystem?